# Probability of at least some with non-equally likely probabilities

Tags: probability

55% of people are male. Out of 5 random people, what is the probability that at least 3 are male?

So I set up the probabilities of 3 male and 2 female, 4 male and 1 female, and 5 males. So I have:

$(\frac{55}{100})^{3} (\frac{45}{100})^{2} + (\frac{55}{100})^{4} \frac{45}{100} + (\frac{55}{100})^5$

But apparently this isn't a correct set-up. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: You should consider mmmff is different from mmfmm - in other words, you are missing the $n \choose k$ term

Answer (score 1):

If you let X be the number of males, then X is a Binomial random variable where *p*=0.55 and *n*=5. You're asked to find P{X > or = 3}=P{X=3}+P{X=4}+P{X=5}.